# Optimal means of obtaining cell address column letter from column index and column index from column letter

Tags: excel, vba, indexing, letter

Typically the accepted approach is to do the following

### Number to Letter

```
public function numberToLetter(ByVal i as long) as string
  Dim s as string: s = cells(1,i).address(false,false)
  numberToLetter = left(s,len(s)-1)
end function
```

### Letter to Number

```
Public Function letterToNumber(ByVal s As String) As Long
  letterToNumber = Range(s & 1).Column
End Function
```

However neither of these are particular optimal, as in each case we are creating an object, and then calling a property accessor on the object. Is there a faster approach?

Comment: You're not creating an object - in both cases the cell already exists.  If you really need to map between a column letter and index then this seems fine to me: with the added bonus it will error if you try to map a non-existent column.

Comment: @TimWilliams I'm pretty certain `range(...)` amd `cells(...)` will create an object, or rather, I'm pretty sure some `2147483647` objects aren't created for every spreadsheet you open (one for each cell in the entire spreadsheet), as this would be extremely slow.

Comment: OK, Fair point...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Summary

The core thing to realise is that the lettering system used in Excel is also known as Base26. `NumberToLetter` is encoding to Base26 from decimal, and `LetterToNumber` is decoding from Base26 to decimal.

Base conversion can be done with simple loops and

```
Function base26Encode(ByVal iDecimal As Long) As String
  if iDecimal <= 0 then Call Err.Raise(5, "base26Encode" ,"Argument cannot be less than 0")
  if iDecimal >= 16384 then Call Err.Raise(5, "base26Encode" ,"There are only 16384 columns in a spreadsheet, thus this function is limited to this number.")
  Dim s As String: s = ""
  Do
    Dim v As Long
    v = (iDecimal - 1) Mod 26 + 1
    iDecimal = (iDecimal - v) / 26
    s = Chr(v + 64) & s
  Loop Until iDecimal = 0
  base26Encode = s
End Function

Function base26Decode(ByVal sBase26 As String) As Long
  sBase26 = UCase(sBase26)
  Dim sum As Long: sum = 0
  Dim iRefLen As Long: iRefLen = Len(sBase26)
  For i = iRefLen To 1 Step -1
    sum = sum + (Asc((Mid(sBase26, i))) - 64) * 26 ^ (iRefLen - i)
  Next
  base26Decode = sum
End Function
```

### Performance

I tested the performance of these functions against the original functions. To do this I used the [`stdPerformance`](https://github.com/sancarn/stdVBA/blob/master/src/stdPerformance.cls) class of stdVBA.

The code used for testing is as follows:

```
Sub testPerf()
  Dim cMax As Long: cMax = 16384
  With stdPerformance.Measure("Encode Original")
    For i = 1 To cMax
      Call numberToLetter(i)
    Next
  End With
  With stdPerformance.Measure("Encode Optimal")
    For i = 1 To cMax
      Call base26Encode(i)
    Next
  End With
  With stdPerformance.Measure("Decode Original")
    For i = 1 To cMax
      Call letterToNumber(base26Encode(i))
    Next
  End With
  With stdPerformance.Measure("Decode Optimal")
    For i = 1 To cMax
      Call base26Decode(base26Encode(i))
    Next
  End With
End Sub
```

The results for which are as follows:

```
Encode Original: 78 ms
Encode Optimal: 31 ms
Decode Original: 172 ms
Decode Optimal: 63 ms
```

As shown this is a slightly faster approach (2-3x faster). I am fairly surprised that object creation and property access performed so well however.

Comment: Instead of `v = iDecimal Mod 26` & `If v = 0 Then v = 26` use `v = (iDecimal - 1) Mod 26 + 1` which has a comparable speed but cleaner code. Also should you pass 0 into the function you get a strange string out so error checking for this would be good.